# MassTransit publish a message when all messages complete

Tags: masstransit

I'm using MassTransit to manage a multiple HTTP post process and want to publish a message when all HTTP posts are complete. Is this possible to do using Sagas? I haven't found any examples of this scenario. Here's my use case example -

- HTTP Post #1 (api/upload) - UploadDataCommand
- HTTP Post #2 (api/upload) - UploadDataCommand
- HTTP Post #3 (api/upload) - UploadDataCommand
- HTTP Post #4 (api/uploadcomplete) - UploadCompleteCommand

So the user does 4 HTTP posts (3 with data, the 4th to signify completion). The upload posts may still be processing when the user posts that the upload is complete, so I want to wait until all uploads are processed AND the upload complete post is sent, before firing another message (UploadProcessingFinished) to move on to other steps in a workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a saga for this, yes. If there are exactly four steps, as you've described above, a single saga with four separate events. Then add a [CompositeEvent](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/automatonymous.html#composite-event) to the saga that is triggered when all four of those events have been handled.

If the steps are variable prior to the completed event, you'd likely want to have either a counter of Start/Finish events from each upload, and a timeout before considering the complete command actually completed. But I would avoid that complexity if possible unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: The number of uploads is variable, which is why we have the final POST where the user signifies that they are done uploading.

Comment: So with the uploads being variable, it sounds like I'm going to keep a counter. Is there any way to query the queue for how many UploadDataCommands exist on the queue (that make some ID's) when the UploadCompleteCommand is received? Or am I going to have to have the user pass in a total number of upload posts they are going to do?

Comment: If the application knows how many parts are being uploaded, you might have them pass that data so you can track one of _n_. There is no way to query the queue, and it wouldn't be reliable anyway if the HTTP client was slow.